# postfix: Relay access denied at remote host

Tags: postfix, docker

I have one postfix instance that I use as main mail server, and that relays all outgoing mail to another postfix instance (using `relayhost`) that then forwards mail to the respective destination.  All is working fine in this configuration (in particular, SPF/DKIM all set up and remote mail servers accept relayed mails perfectly fine), where the relaying postfix is running natively on Debian.

Now I want to replace the relaying postfix with one running inside Docker, based on Alpine Linux (which might have a slightly different default configuration than Debian).  The full `main.cf` config is below (where everything before the blank line is from the system's default config, and everything below the blank line is what I explicitly set):

```
compatibility_level = 3.7
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/readme
inet_protocols = ipv4
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
meta_directory = /etc/postfix

maillog_file = /dev/stdout
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mydomain (Linux/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
alias_maps = lmdb:/etc/aliases
alias_database = lmdb:/etc/aliases
message_size_limit = 30000000
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = relay.domob.eu
myorigin = domob.eu
mydomain = domob.eu
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl/
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = localhost
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/key.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/cert.pem
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

This does not work.  If I try to send outgoing mail, I believe it gets relayed fine to the postfix inside Docker, accepted there, but then rejected by the remote host.  Logs are as follows:

```
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:23 relay postfix/smtpd[83]: connect from unknown[172.30.0.1]
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:23 relay postfix/smtpd[83]: 784B361A73: client=unknown[172.30.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=rpi@localhost
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:23 relay postfix/cleanup[88]: 784B361A73: message-id=<a7b2f905-fc18-a706-77f2-f7e583e01074@domob.eu>
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:23 relay postfix/qmgr[75]: 784B361A73: from=<d@domob.eu>, size=3834, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:23 relay postfix/smtpd[83]: disconnect from unknown[172.30.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:24 relay postfix/smtp[89]: 784B361A73: to=<domob1812@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]:25, delay=0.74, delays=0.03/0.02/0.66/0.03, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26] said: 554 5.7.1 <domob1812@gmail.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command))
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:24 relay postfix/cleanup[88]: 39DAB61A75: message-id=<20220824135124.39DAB61A75@relay.domob.eu>
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:24 relay postfix/qmgr[75]: 39DAB61A75: from=<>, size=5840, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:24 relay postfix/bounce[90]: 784B361A73: sender non-delivery notification: 39DAB61A75
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:24 relay postfix/qmgr[75]: 784B361A73: removed
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:25 relay postfix/smtp[89]: 39DAB61A75: to=<d@domob.eu>, relay=mail.domob.eu[51.68.174.164]:25, delay=0.99, delays=0/0/0.52/0.46, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as BD1473EC67)
relay-postfix-postfix-1  | Aug 24 13:51:25 relay postfix/qmgr[75]: 39DAB61A75: removed
```

Unfortunately, all information that I could find about "Relay access denied" always is about the relaying postfix denying access, not the remote host (and of course I also don't have access to Gmail's server logs).  What is wrong with my config / setting?

Comment: Please, fill "from=" and "to=" back, at least, use actual domain names. For now, I can only speculate that the "envelope from" domain is served by gmail servers, or more strange, "envelope from" isn't server by gmail servers, but your system thinks it should be delivered it to gmail. Or they get so tired of you so decided to block your server altogether.

Comment: The logs are verbatim from the server, in case you think I have redacted them (or maybe postfix redacts them in logs?).  But maybe that points to a potential issue?  Note that relaying from the "native" postfix instance running on Debian works fine, so the server itself (e.g. the IP) has not been blocked for sure.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the [manual of Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en) 5.7.1 says that Google did not accept the mail but the rest can be read in the manual ;)

Comment: See `from=,` and `to=,` in the question? There were actual addresses. They were in angle brackets in the log file, and if you copied that "as is" the ServerFault parser "removed the unknown tag". Nevertheless, you need to fix that.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Ah I get it now, thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: @djdomi Thanks for the pointer.  But to me, all mention of this error at Google indicate that Google expects an authenticated user.  In my case, what I'm trying to do is relay mail *to* a Gmail account, which should be accepted without authentication.  Does that mean my postfix config is wrong somehow?  (Note that relaying to Gmail works fine from the same server/IP with another postfix instance.)

Comment: There is at least misconfiguration in the DNS: MX for your domain is `mail.domob.eu`, and the the server's seems to know its hostname, but `mail.domob.eu` resolves to `51.68.174.164` which resolves back to `i0coin.domob.eu` (other name). Better fix this to be all consistent. Also I hope your server really makes outgoing connections from `51.68.174.164` (which is the only permitted by the SPF record), because the mail will be rejected like that otherwise. I suggest you to confirm this to be sure. // No, this is not the indication that it requires authentication. It "just dosn't want your mail".

Comment: Nikita you are right. dns issue is a common rejection reason for this kind

Comment: Yes, the outgoing mail is sent from `51.68.174.164`, which is the server's IP on which I try to run postfix in Docker (and as mentioned, all works fine if I send mail from this same server via postfix running natively in Debian instead of hosted via Docker).

`mail.domob.eu` and `i0coin.domob.eu` resolve to the same IP.  I can change the reverse DNS to `mail.domob.eu` if you think that helps, but in general this server has been able to send mail just fine for multiple years now.  The issue is the new postfix inside Docker.